# For loop over 3 matrices

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have three 2D arrays with the same size:

```
import numpy as np
rArray = np.ones((3,3))
gArray = np.ones((3,3))*2
bArray = np.ones((3,3))*3
```

I want to loop over them element by element, so that I can make some calculations and then store the result in a new array:

```
data = np.zeros(rArray.shape)
for r,g,b in .... :
  res=2*r + g - b
  data[i,j] = res
```

where `r` belongs to `rArray`, and so on.

**EDIT1:**

```
# Python program to get average of a list 
def Average(lst): 
    return sum(lst) / len(lst)

# TURBO
from sympy import symbols, solve
import numpy as np

minValue = -140; maxValue = -80

a = 1 / (maxValue - minValue)
c = (-minValue) / (maxValue - minValue)

from osgeo import gdal, gdal_array
import sys, os
file=os.getcwd() + '/doc.kml'
ds = gdal.Open(file)
if ds is None:
    print('Unable to open raster file')
    sys.exit(1)
band1 = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
band2 = ds.GetRasterBand(2)
band3 = ds.GetRasterBand(3)
rArray = band1.ReadAsArray()
gArray = band2.ReadAsArray()
bArray = band3.ReadAsArray()

data = np.zeros(rArray.shape)
i=0; j=0
for (rRow,gRow,bRow) in zip(rArray,gArray,bArray):
    j=0
    for (r,g,b) in zip(rRow,gRow,bRow):
        if r==35 and g==23 and b==27: data[i,j] = np.nan
        else:
            colorCode = symbols('x', real=True, positive=True)

            expr = 34.61 + colorCode * (1172.33 - colorCode * (10793.56 - colorCode * (33300.12 - colorCode * (38394.49 - colorCode * 14825.05))))
            sol_R = solve(expr - r, colorCode)
            #print("R: " + str(sol_R))

            expr = 23.31 + colorCode * (557.33 + colorCode * (1225.33 - colorCode * (3574.96 - colorCode * (1073.77 + colorCode * 707.56))))
            sol_G = solve(expr - g, colorCode)
            #print("G: " + str(sol_G))

            expr = 27.2 + colorCode * (3211.1 - colorCode * (15327.97 - colorCode * (27814 - colorCode * (22569.18 - colorCode * 6838.66))))
            sol_B = solve(expr - b, colorCode)
            #print("B: " + str(sol_B))

            '''iList = []
            arr = np.array(sol_R + sol_G + sol_B)
            arr2 = np.less_equal(np.abs(arr[:, np.newaxis] - arr[np.newaxis, :]), 0.1).astype(int)
            for iRow, iCol in np.transpose(np.triu_indices_from(arr2, k=1)):
                if arr2[iRow, iCol]:
                    iList.append([iRow, iCol])
                    print(iRow, iCol)
            ''' 

            colorCode = []
            delta=10
            for r in sol_R:
                for g in sol_G:
                    if np.absolute(r-g) < delta: 
                        colorCode.clear()
                        delta = np.absolute(r-g)
                        colorCode.append(r); colorCode.append(g)

            delta=10
            for b in sol_B:
                if np.absolute(b - Average(colorCode)) < delta: 
                    delta = np.absolute(b-Average(colorCode))
                    colorCodeValue = Average(colorCode+[b])

            value = symbols('x', real=True)
            expr = value*a + c
            sol = solve(expr - colorCodeValue, value)
            if sol[0] < minValue: sol[0] = minValue
            elif sol[0] > maxValue: sol[0] = maxValue
            #print(i,j)
            data[i,j] = sol[0]

        j+=1
    i+=1


# save array, using ds as a prototype
gdal_array.SaveArray(data.astype("float32"), os.getcwd() + '/power.tif', "GTIFF", ds)

ds = None
```

File is here: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kbqleeyt5xzyo17/doc.kml?dl=0)

Comment: You can use `zip`. `for r, g, b in zip(rArray, gArray, bArray):`

Comment: I've already tried that, that way 'r', 'g' and 'b' are the rows, not the values

Comment: Then why not go one more layer down? `for rRow, gRow, bRow in zip(rArray, gArray, bArray): for r, g, b in zip(rRow, gRow, bRow):`

Comment: Why not `data = rArray * 2 + gArray - bArray` without any explicit loops?

Comment: What I've shown here is simplified. In reality, I have to use the elements in the arrays to solve equations (using sympy). Sympy doesn't allow calcs with arrays

Comment: Why don't you add some more of the code, for loops in python are horribly slow when doing big calculations :/ so being able to utilize vector/matrix operations will often make things a lot faster (as well as often being more readable than nested for loops). If you want to use for loops the mentioned zip() method is your friend :)

Comment: @VegardJervell code above

Answer (score 1):

If, like you've said in comments, you need only single values (`float` or `int` or what have you), the best way to iterate through arrays one element at a time is to use either `ndarray.ravel()` or `ndarray.flatten()`. The difference between these is that `ravel` allows you to modify the original array while you're looping, whereas `flatten` makes a copy. For your case you aren't trying to modify the arrays, so [ravel is faster](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html).

Note that this won't keep track of indices regardless, so the `i` and `j` in your code don't make sense.

```
data = np.zeros(rArray.shape)
for r,g,b in zip(rArray.ravel(),gArray.ravel(),bArray.ravel()):
  res=2*r + g - b
```

**EDIT:**
Since you need to keep track of indices you are probably best looping through both similar to how you have it. Using `enumerate` is much more pythonic and means you don't have to keep track of indices as you're editing and debugging code. I've modified your loop block to use those, and also your variables so they don't conflict with the loop variables. This code works for me.

```
for i,rows in enumerate(zip(rArray,gArray,bArray)):
    for j,(r,g,b) in enumerate(zip(*rows)):
        if r==35 and g==23 and b==27: data[i,j] = np.nan
        else:
            colorCode = symbols('x', real=True, positive=True)

            expr = 34.61 + colorCode * (1172.33 - colorCode * (10793.56 - colorCode * (33300.12 - colorCode * (38394.49 - colorCode * 14825.05))))
            sol_R = solve(expr - r, colorCode)
            #print("R: " + str(sol_R))

            expr = 23.31 + colorCode * (557.33 + colorCode * (1225.33 - colorCode * (3574.96 - colorCode * (1073.77 + colorCode * 707.56))))
            sol_G = solve(expr - g, colorCode)
            #print("G: " + str(sol_G))

            expr = 27.2 + colorCode * (3211.1 - colorCode * (15327.97 - colorCode * (27814 - colorCode * (22569.18 - colorCode * 6838.66))))
            sol_B = solve(expr - b, colorCode)
            #print("B: " + str(sol_B))

            colorCode = []
            delta=10
            for r_sol in sol_R:
                for g_sol in sol_G:
                    if np.absolute(r_sol-g_sol) < delta: 
                        colorCode.clear()
                        delta = np.absolute(r_sol-g_sol)
                        colorCode.append(r_sol); colorCode.append(g_sol)

            delta=10
            for b_sol in sol_B:
                if np.absolute(b_sol - Average(colorCode)) < delta: 
                    delta = np.absolute(b_sol-Average(colorCode))
                    colorCodeValue = Average(colorCode+[b_sol])

            value = symbols('x', real=True)
            expr = value*a + c 
            sol = solve(expr - colorCodeValue, value)
            if sol[0] < minValue:
                sol[0] = minValue
            elif sol[0] > maxValue:
                sol[0] = maxValue
            data[i,j] = sol[0]
```

Comment: I need to keep track of indices